# How to activate macros in WPS Spreadsheets 2021 in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: libreoffice, wps-office

I'm trying to compare LibreOffice version 6.4.7.2 Calc with WPS Spreadsheets in terms of how macros are handles. I imported an Excel spreadsheet containing many macros into WPS Office Spreadsheets 2021. I'm referring to the Personal Edition of WPS Office Spreadsheets. Macros do not work because they are not enabled. How do I enable all macros, and edit them in the WPS Office Linux version 11.1.0.10702? I've used macros in Excel for many years, and I'm looking for a replacement spreadsheet as I continue to become Microsoft free.

Comment: I should add that I'm referring to the Personal Edition of WPS Office Spreadsheets

Comment: Your question title does not match the body of your question.  It is not clear what you are asking.  Please edit your question and make sure that there is a clear focused question.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot enable or use Macros in the Free/Personal/Business version of WPS Office 2019.
The only version that supports Macros is WPS Office Enterprise Edition/Version.
This is not available on their website. You have to buy it from you local WPS distributor.